# I have my log file path in the database how to pass that in logstash?

Tags: logstash

How to pass filepath which is there in DB to configure lagstash. 
I can get the file path using input jdbc plugin from database it works. But how to pass the file path from there.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash reads a static config file.  There was talk of an API in logstash2 that seemingly could have provided what you were looking for, but it has been pushed back to a future release.